# Is 'Kay a shortened form of Okay?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, collocations, exclamatives

This is from an interview by Vogue [73 questions with Cindy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGVVuoOarbs) (see 03:01-03:06)

The reporter asks questions to a celebrity. Right before one of the questions, he says:

**'Kay Cindy, what is something that you would never wear in a million years."**

As you see, the first word starts with an apostrophe and is followed by **Kay** starting with a capital letter.

I thought he meant **"Okay"** and subtitle writers simply shortened it to **'Kay**, just like **because** is shortened to **'Cos**.

Am I right in my thinking? Did he simply mean **Okay** and **'Kay** is simply the short of **"Okay"?**

Comment: You are completely correct.

Comment: Before we discovered thumbs up emoticons, I'm sure *millions* of sms text messages were just the single letter **K**

Comment: @FumbleFingers - before the 'word' _okay_ was invented, we used to just say and write 'OK'. Sauce, corral, whatever.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: You learn something new every day. Until I just googled "ok etymology" after seeing your comment, I'd actually just supposed it came from WW2 American military slang (I was at least a century behind the times, there! :) As to the OK Corral, I thought that was just two letters that ought to be easily recognised in the context of cattle branding - if pressed, and knowing that most brands are just one letter/symbol rather than two, I'd have guessed that the OK corral was reserved for the two big local ranchers, one of whom used **O**, and the other used **K** as their brands!

Comment: (I mean when the corral was being used for cattle, even though from our perspective today it might well have been *exclusively* reserved for shoot-outs! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - you were perhaps not a fan of Westerns? The Old Kindersley Corral (of Wyatt Earp fame) wasn't really anything to do with the slang expression used to express agreement. I first read of the 'Orl Korrect' theory on an OK Sauce bottle label around 1960.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I'm a *fanatical* fan of Westerns! I started using *Eric's Movie Database* nearly 15 years ago to log every movie I watch, and I replaced that with my own hand-crafted (with much help from QT Creator! :) program and database when EMDB started getting too slow with its oversized database. So I just filtered in my app to see all movies that include "western" in the genre. As of right now I've logged 603 Western movies. Top of the ratings are *Unforgiven, TGTBATU, and Once Upon a Time in the West*, but in at number 4 is Tarantino's more recent offering *Django Unchained*.

Comment: *Gunfight at the O.K. Corral (1957)* didn't really do it for me though - it comes in at about number 300 out of those 603 Western movies!

Comment: I don't know why this question has been downvoted. It's a reasonable question from an English learner given that people *do* say it, and it isn't in a dictionary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not really a 'shortened form' so much as a dropped syllable. People *do* say it, but you're unlikely to find it in a scholarly dictionary because it is technically incorrect.

It's worth noting that there are other, deliberate, alternate forms of saying 'okay', such as "*okie dokie*". The TV show *South Park* also popularised saying "*mmm'kay*". It's possible that some people say "*kay*" deliberately.

Comment: My guess is those subtitles were automatically produced by a bot, and it incorrectly guessed that that word was the name "Kay", rather than just "K".

Comment: @gotube I don't think the auto-transcript bot would have put the apostrophe in as the OP states, indicating a shortening.

Comment: I read that as the opening of the quote of the subtitle, rather than an apostrophe, but who knows